# How to filter a QuerySet with the results of another QuerySet in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

Right now I have a Django QuerySet that I want to filter by the result of another QuerySet. Right now I am doing this like so (and it works):

```
field = 'content_object__pk'
values = other_queryset.values_list(field, flat=True)
objects = queryset.filter(pk__in=values)
```

where the field is the name of a foreign key, the `pk` in `queryset`. The ORM is smart enough to run the above as one query.

I was trying to simplify this to (ie to filter with the object list themselves rather than having to explicitly say `pk`):

```
field = 'content_object'
objects = queryset & other_queryset.values_list(field, flat=True)
```

but this gives the following error:

```
AssertionError: Cannot combine queries on two different base models.
```

What is the right way to do this type of filtering?

Answer (score 12):

You can do the next:

```
result = MyModel.objects.filter(field__in=other_query)
```

The results will be the objects in the model where the field is a foreign key to the model in the other_query

Answer (score -3):

you can chain queries in Django...

```
qs = entry.objects.filter(...).filter(...)
```

Comment: I understand, but in this case what goes in the ... ? Can you put `.filer(in=...)` (my thought is no).

Comment: yes, you can put Person.objects.filter(name="michael").filter(lastname="riemann")

Comment: Those are both examples with string filters. It doesn't answer how to use a queryset.

Comment: Every table in a database should have a primary key.. If two tables are related to one another, this should be represented with a foreign key, one-to-one, or many to many relationship.. When you query one table, reference the primary key of the relationship to the other table in the method I showed... You don't use a query set to make a query, you use tuples and relations to select the data you need even if its across multiple tables

Comment: I understand the concept of pk an fk. I presented a solution that does just that. My question is whether there is batter way to write the query other than the on I presented.